# How can I see the global environment in pycharm similar to Rstudio?

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, rstudio

I have been work with R in Rstudio since 2013, but now I decide to move to Python and I have been used Pycharm IDE. This IDE is very stable and friendly, but I can't see the objects and the results of the code processing.

My question is: How can I see the global environment (like Rstudio). It's important to see what my code has doing.

Any idea to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Python Console (Tools --> Python Console). On the left side of the python console, there is a button called Show variable (Below the question mark button). It will allow you to see the global variables like RStudio.

If you are writing a script, you can use the Debugger. You can read more about it [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debugging.html)

Comment: Great! Thanks!
I found the Rodeo IDE that has some characteristics similar as Rstudio.

Comment: Good to know, though you might also want to know how to Alt-Shft-E (Execute Line in Console) or you won't get any resulting objects in the Console.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a bit too late, but for those who just see this, pycharm now supports the scientific mode, which for me is even better compare to Rstudio(R)

Comment: FWIW this mode is only available in the professional / paid versions.